# Find string in combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, special-characters

I have a string value with special characters like í, é, ë, ï etc. For example "San Luis Potosí". This value has been applied to a field in my application from a combobox on my form. Later on I want to find that value again in the combobox so the combobox is showing that value already. For 'normal' values it is working as expected and the combobox is showing the right value, but for values as "San Luis Potosí", "'s-Hertogenbosch" it is not. Is there a special thing I have to do in regards to these special characters?

Edit:

```
//Example:
txtLocation = "San Luis Potosí, Mexico";

string[] location = txtLocation.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                string city = location[0]; // city = "San Luis Potosí" (this works)
                string country = location[1]; // country = "Mexico" (this works)

                comboBoxCountry.SelectedIndex = comboBoxCountry.FindStringExact(country);
                comboBoxCity.SelectedIndex = comboBoxCity.FindStringExact(city);
```

The comboboxes are filed by a dataset from a database. I am using winforms, framework .Net 4.6.1.

I just notice that it isn't working with any value. It appears it has nothing to do with any special characters.

I get these values when debugging.
comboBoxCountry.SelectedIndex = -1
comboBoxCity.SelectedIndex = -1

Comment: could you please 1) be more specific about "not working" and 2) show your code?

Comment: Also, please specify the UI framework you use (WPF, WinForms, Xamarin, UWP, ASP.NET, Unity, ...)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, a method to load the database was called twice and overwrote the found values.